# re.search (python) with positive indexing

Tags: python-2.7

i have this:

```
find = "user=admin user=root user=lol"
```

i want to extract the user lol using re.search , i tryed using re.search

```
import re

print re.search(r'user=(.*)', find).group(1)
```

but it give me :

```
admin user=root user=lol
```

i tryed using negative indexing :

```
print re.search(r'user=(.*)',find).group(1)[-1]
```

but it give me 1 letter:

```
>>> print re.search(r'user=(.*)', find).group(1)[-1]
l
>>>
```

and i tryed this :

```
f = re.search(r'user=(.*)', find)
print f.group(1)[-1] + f.group(1)[-2] + f.group(1)[-3]
```

it give me :

```
>>> print f.group(1)[-1] + f.group(1)[-2] + f.group(1)[-3]
lol
>>>
```

it work , but i don't want that , i don't want to repeat that every time , i want directly

thanks for who answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` and non-capturing group `(?:)`:

```
re.search(r'\b(?:user=)(.+?)\b', find).group(1)
#admin
```

And to catch all of them, use `findall`:

```
re.findall(r'\b(?:user=)(.+?)\b', find)
#['admin', 'root', 'lol']
```

To get the `lol` just use last element:

```
re.findall(r'\b(?:user=)(.+?)\b', find)[-1]
#lol
```

Comment: but wait , it not working really , look here: print re.search(r'\b(?:user=)(.+?)\b', find).group(1)[-1] , it give me 1 letter : n , not lol

Comment: Why `[-1]`? You got what you need with solution

Comment: oh , sorry , it work , ibecause i did a mistake , i used re.search , but i was needing to use re.findall , sorry again